# What features were lost in 12.10 when the Alternate CD was cut?

Tags: 12.10, system-installation, alternate

Some of the Alternate CD features were added to the Desktop CD (like full encryption) but some were lost (like RAID).

What other features were lost?

Comment: Maybe someone wants to dig through this and make a list: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-August/thread.html#35675